# auto click submit form php on page load

Tags: php, forms

please help me,, I'm confused,,
I want when I after opening the page, the page directly auto submit

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="url" value="google.com">
<input type="max" name="max" value="9999">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
require("autovisitor.class.php");

$url = "google.com";
$max = 999;

for($i = 1; $i < $max+1; $i++) {
$class = new autovisitor($url);
echo $i.". SUKSES - [".$class->jalankan()."]<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: do you mean to submit the form after a specific period of time _automatically_?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with an auto-submitting form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246731/trouble-with-an-auto-submitting-form)

Answer (score 3):

Give the `form` an ID:

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="url" value="google.com">
  <input type="max" name="max" value="9999">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then immediately:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :  ( using jquery plugins )

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm" action="">
    <input type="text" name="url" value="google.com">
    <input type="max" name="max" value="9999">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

 <script>

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit;
     });
    </script>
```

Define id for the form and action attribute.

Comment: This is not a jQuery question. Avoid using it. Plus, how is it different from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This script will submit your form after a specific time (5 seconds).

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms['myform'].submit();
}, 5000);
</script>

<form method="POST" name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="url" value="google.com">
  <input type="max" name="max" value="9999">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```